# Header not in Row 1 CSV Import Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import

I'm trying to import CSV files and the header row keeps moving around, sometimes it's in row 20, sometimes it's in 25, and so on, but the field 'SPIRIT Barcode' is always in the header and it's the only thing I'm interested in at this point. I'm saving it in "barcode".

How do I manipulate this to find the row 'SPIRIT Barcode' is in and use that as the header? (everything above the header can be ignored)

```
def self.import(file)
 @b = []
 CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
  entry = ZygReport.find_by(barcode: row['SPIRIT Barcode']) || new
  entry.update({
    :barcode => row['SPIRIT Barcode'],
    })
  entry.save!
  @b << [entry.barcode]
 end
end
```

Ignore the `@b`, that's for another function.

Comment: You might have to rewrite your file before parsing it. Does your header row have any distinguishing characteristics that can help you find it?

Comment: It has distinguishing words like "TALLY" and "SPIRIT Barcode" among a few others that aren't anywhere else in the files

Comment: is the file small enough to be able to read entirely in memory?

Comment: typically <500Kb, few dozen to few thousand lines

Comment: Find that line, shunt it to the top, feed the revised version to `CSV.parse`.

Comment: Your question isn't asked well. Please read "[mcve]". You need to provide a tiny example of the input CSV instead of expecting us to generate one to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This code parses the file only once, reading it line by line and looking for `SPIRIT Barcode`.

Once the line is found, it removes the newline, and splits it to get an array of header names.

`CSV.parse` can be called on the file directly. Since it has already been read until the header, it will start at the correct line :

```
require 'csv'
sep = ';'
File.open('test.csv'){|file|
 header = file.find{|line| line.include?('SPIRIT Barcode')}.chomp.split(sep)
 CSV.parse(file, headers: header, col_sep: sep).each do |row|
   p row
 end
}
```

With `test.csv` as :

```
Ignore me
Ignore me
SPIRIT Barcode; B; C
1; 2; 3
4; 5; 6
```

It outputs :

```
#<CSV::Row "SPIRIT Barcode":"1" " B":" 2" " C":" 3">
#<CSV::Row "SPIRIT Barcode":"4" " B":" 5" " C":" 6">
```

It shouldn't be hard to adapt it to your data.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but it's the general idea for what you're trying to do:

```
require 'csv'

header_found = false
File.foreach('path/to/file.csv') do |li|
  next unless header_found || li['SPIRIT Barcode']
  header_found = true
  # start processing CSV...
  CSV.parse(li) do |row|
    # use row here...
  end
end
```

You'll have to figure out what to do when the header is found if you want to keep track of the values.

Comment: You don't use the header, do you?